# Oracle parallel query: finding out which Producer a Consumer is waiting for

Tags: oracle, parallelism

One of our materialized view refresh's (part of a daily ETL routine) was hanging today; it usually completes within 5 minutes, but this time, I had to kill it after 23 hours.

V$SESSION contained this information:

```
SID   USERNAME  BLOCKING_SESSION  EVENT                   P1TEXT
491   USER1                       PX Deq: Table Q Normal  sleeptime/senderid
1073  USER1     491               PX Deq: Execute Reply   sleeptime/senderid
```

So it seems that SID 1073 (presumably the query coordinator) was waiting for SID 491 (a parallel consumer), which itself was waiting for data from at least one producer (according to [Doug Burn's paper "Tuning Parallel Execution"](http://oracledoug.com/px.pdf), that's the meaning of *PX Deq: Table Q Normal* ). But there was no BLOCKING_SESSION for the consumer session.

How can I find the parallel producer session the consumer is waiting for?

Comment: Did you try to run his query that uses v$pq_tqstat? Perhaps that might help? If a consumer is waiting on a producer, then you could also query v$px_sesstat to find more information.

Comment: Should I query v$pq_tqstat to find out which producer is to blame? v$px_sesstat seems to be useless to me, since it provides information only about the current session, and I cannot run it in the session because it hangs (and was started by a dbms_scheduler job).